# Changing java platform on which netbeans runs

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using Netbeans 6.7. I had first installed Java 1.5 before installing Netbeans. When i installed Netbeans it took Java 1.5 as the default version. Then i installed Java 1.6 on my machine. I need to change the default JDK of my netbeans to 1.6 not only to a specific project but to the whole Netbeans application.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

You can change the JDK for Netbeans by modifying the config file:

1. Open `netbeans.conf` file available under `etc` folder inside the NetBeans installation.
2. Modify the `netbeans_jdkhome` variable to point to new JDK path, and then
3. Restart your Netbeans.

Comment: For those who already had netbeans_jdkhome with >=7 version. Put the Java EE API library into the Library folder and don't forget to set JDK 7 by right clicking on project and choosing Properties->Sources and set Source/Binary format select JDK7 among options.

Comment: I keep getting error 
Invalid jdkhome specified
---------------------------
Cannot locate java installation in specified jdkhome:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.5.0_03\bin";
Do you want to try to use default version?"

Comment: @Enthusiastic you don't need to include `bin` in the path try like this: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.5.0_03\`

Comment: @AbdelRaoof, gives the same error for that path as well.

Comment: On OSX, I do "cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines" to find the different JDKs on my Mac. The version I want to use is "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home".

Then at /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/etc/netbeans.conf, I add this line:

`netbeans_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home"`

Answer (score 34):

In my Windows 7 box I found **netbeans.conf** in `<Drive>:\<Program Files folder>\<NetBeans installation folder>\etc` .  Thanks all.

Answer (score 32):

For anyone on Mac OS X, you can find `netbeans.conf` here:

```
/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans <version>.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/etc/netbeans.conf
```

In case anyone needs to know :)

Comment: `netbeans_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home"` for example

Answer (score 12):

open etc folder in netbeans folder then edit the netbeans.conf with notepad and you will find a line like this :

> Default location of JDK, can be
>   overridden by using --jdkhome
>   :
>   netbeans_jdkhome="G:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_13"

here you can set your jdk version.

Comment: if that path even exists

Answer (score 1):

Fix this by moving my jdk folder to other disk

Answer (score 0):

on Fedora it is currently impossible to set a new jdk-HOME to some sdk. They designed it such that it will always break. Try --jdkhome [whatever] but in all likelihood it will break and show some cryptic nonsensical error message as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Either change the jdk home in the application preferences or look for the application's config files.

On Mac OS X, its in a `netbeans.conf` file, and look for the `jdk home` value.

here:[image]