# Netbeans does not recognize the Java folder

Tags: java, netbeans-8

After some experiences with Scratch, they told me the best option for beginners is Java, if I want to learn something usefulin future. I downloaded Java SE (JDK 10) and Netbeans and  installed both. Netbeans ask for a folder that is Java, which I just installed. But it doesn't recognize the folder and says firstly no compatible version found and later the specified JDK folder does not contain JDK. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have installed JDK 10 I guess. There was a contradiction in your question since you have downloaded JDK10 and installed JDK8. First of all, I would like to mention that the latest version of of Netbeans supports only JDK8.
Try installing JDK 8 and reconfigure Netbeans accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. Do the newer versions have some benefits compared to the JDK8 so should I search for something else than Netbeans or are they pretty similar, so that it is not worth to search for different IDE?

Comment: I would recommend you to go with Eclipse since it is pretty open to anything. In other words, you can install any version of JDK in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans only supports JDK 8. Install that and point to the folder for JDK 8 when NetBeans asks. If it doesn't ask again you can do it manually, shown here [Changing java platform on which netbeans runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809366/changing-java-platform-on-which-netbeans-runs)