# Why won't Netbeans create a project?

Tags: netbeans-8

I am trying to use NetBeans to code in Java. Problem is, whenever I try to create a new project via the 'New Project' button, it gives me the notification: 'Unexpected Exception.' I am using Netbeans 8.2 and Java Development Kit 12.0.2.

I have tried both new project buttons, and also tried the new file button just in case. They all give the exact same notification.

I expected it to create a new file instead of giving an error notification, is there something I may have done incorrectly, or not done when I was supposed to?

Comment: There is more information than `Unexpected Exception`?

Comment: Regarding _"I am using Netbeans 8.2 and Java Development Kit 12.0.2."_, that is an invalid combination. If you are using NetBeans 8.2 then you must use JDK 8. JDK 12 is not supported, and will not work. Alternatively, if your priority is to use JDK 12 then [download and install Apache NetBeans 11.0 instead](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb110/nb110.html). You do not need to uninstall NetBeans 8.2 to use NetBeans 11.0, and you can even safely run both versions at the same time.

Comment: In response to Dani, no, that is all it gives me.

Comment: How can I use JDK 8? Is there a way to do it without having to reinstall the JDK?

Comment: @Exabyte314 To use JDK 8 with NetBeans 8.2: [1] Download and install JDK 8 if necessary. [2] Configure NetBeans 8.2 to use JDK 8. See [Changing java platform on which netbeans runs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2809366/2985643) for details on how to do that. You can safely leave your existing installation of JDK 12 in place, or remove it if you wish. Either way it won't matter with respect to using NetBeans 8.2 with JDK 8.

Comment: @Exabyte314 Just FYI, if you want to communicate with someone else using a comment, within that comment include their username prefixed with the **@** symbol. Doing that ensures that the other user will be made aware of your comment.