# Changing the default JKD WITHOUT editing the "netbeans.conf" file directly?

Tags: java, settings, default

Surely after 10+ years, there is a Netbeans 11.2 menu option to set the default Java JDK after upgrading the JDK?

I've found the "ADD" JDK, where the "DEFAULT" is listed under "TOOLS"/"JAVA PLATFORMS".  But I can't set v17 as the default?

The JDK has been updated from 8 to SEVENTEEN in...what...4 years?  Why make this "HARD"!?

Comment: Because Netbeans was usually released alongside a new JDK. Why don't you upgrade to Apache NetBeans 12.5 (which was released on September 13, 2021)? Why are you using such an old release of NetBeans? How do you expect it to *update itself*? Where did 4 years come from?

Comment: WELL, that's a FINE Queanswer!  I'll DO IT.  Right now.  But, will 12."6" stop my crying??

Comment: I doubt it. That's [always how it has worked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809366/changing-java-platform-on-which-netbeans-runs).

Comment: Ha!  And why not.  I DELETED IT ALL...and started over.  "It's the only way to be sure." ;-)  Thanks for the tip on 12.6 anyway...thought I had the latest.  And now, I have something else to relearn when the next updates come out.