# How do I customize the startup user interface in Netbeans 13

Tags: netbeans

I would like to know how to customize the startup window panels/ui in Netbeans 13 so it effectively persists across IDE reboots.

On the left sidebar panel, it opens with `Projects`, `Files`, and `Services`, and `Navigator` on the lower half of this when the IDE is opened.

On the bottom panel, I have `Notifications` that always opens, even when there are none to review.

The panels that I configure do not persist across IDE startups, and always revert to these defaults. Typically the panels that I use are the following:

In the left sidebar, `Projects` and `Services`
and in the bottom taskbar, `Terminal`

But these do not persist when the IDE is closed and reopened, instead always reverting to the aforementioned defaults.

---

Originally my files that were open also did not persist across IDE startups after updating to v13, but this was corrected by running `Window > Reset Windows` and restarting the IDE, they now restore on startup as expected. This had no effect on the sidebar panels or terminal however.
*(thank you @skomisa for reminding me to do this)*

---

Some context on my system environment:

- I have updated on this system since Netbeans version 12.4, performing the standard import process for settings on each subsequent upgrade.
- I was unable to find documentation online for the current version. Most relevant documentation available applied to version 7.2 or 8.1
- I am on Manjaro Linux. My preferences folder is located at `/home/mopsyd/.netbeans/13/`, with a folder permission of `755`. Files inside of this appear to follow the correct file permission format at cursory glance.

---

Contents of **View > IDE Log**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>Log Session: Monday, April 25, 2022 1:02:22 AM EDT
>System Info: 
  Product Version         = Apache NetBeans IDE 13
  Operating System        = Linux version 5.4.188-1-MANJARO running on amd64
  Java; VM; Vendor        = 1.8.0_332; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 25.332-b04; Oracle Corporation
  Runtime                 = OpenJDK Runtime Environment 1.8.0_332-b04
  Java Home               = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre
  System Locale; Encoding = en_US (nb); UTF-8
  Home Directory          = /home/mopsyd
  Current Directory       = /home/mopsyd
  User Directory          = /home/mopsyd/.netbeans/13
  Cache Directory         = /home/mopsyd/.cache/netbeans/13
  Installation            = /usr/lib/netbeans/nb
                            /usr/lib/netbeans/ergonomics
                            /usr/lib/netbeans/ide
                            /usr/lib/netbeans/extide
                            /usr/lib/netbeans/java
                            /usr/lib/netbeans/apisupport
                            /usr/lib/netbeans/webcommon
                            /usr/lib/netbeans/websvccommon
                            /usr/lib/netbeans/enterprise
                            /usr/lib/netbeans/profiler
                            /usr/lib/netbeans/php
                            /usr/lib/netbeans/harness
                            /usr/lib/netbeans/groovy
                            /usr/lib/netbeans/javafx
                            /usr/lib/netbeans/platform
  Boot & Ext. Classpath   = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/classes:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/mariadb-java-client.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar
  Application Classpath   = /usr/lib/netbeans/platform/lib/boot.jar:/usr/lib/netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-modules.jar:/usr/lib/netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util.jar:/usr/lib/netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util-lookup.jar:/usr/lib/netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util-ui.jar
  Startup Classpath       = /usr/lib/netbeans/platform/core/org-netbeans-libs-asm.jar:/usr/lib/netbeans/platform/core/asm-tree-9.2.jar:/usr/lib/netbeans/platform/core/asm-9.2.jar:/usr/lib/netbeans/platform/core/asm-commons-9.2.jar:/usr/lib/netbeans/platform/core/core-base.jar:/usr/lib/netbeans/platform/core/org-openide-filesystems.jar:/usr/lib/netbeans/platform/core/core.jar:/usr/lib/netbeans/platform/core/org-openide-filesystems-compat8.jar:/usr/lib/netbeans/nb/core/org-netbeans-upgrader.jar:/usr/lib/netbeans/nb/core/locale/core_nb.jar
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.netbinox]: Install area set to file:/usr/lib/netbeans/
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: the modules [org.netbeans.modules.xml.text] use org.netbeans.modules.editor.deprecated.pre65formatting which is deprecated.
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: the modules [org.netbeans.modules.ide.kit, org.netbeans.modules.xml.text] use org.netbeans.modules.editor.structure which is deprecated.
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.cnd.apt.debug.APTTraceFlags]: C/C++ code model: using old [ CND ] preprocessor
INFO [org.netbeans.core.startup.NbEvents]: Turning on modules:



   ** 
   MODULE LOADOUT TRUNCATED DUE TO
   MESSAGE LENGTH EXCEEDING ALLOWABLE 
   POST LIMIT
   **



    org.netbeans.modules.editor.deprecated.pre65formatting/0 [1.46.0.1.6.23.55 1 13-00d6d969bf4d9b14e7406c9ee9cc13a61dc39655]

INFO [org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso]: bundle org.eclipse.osgi@3.9.1.v20140110-1610 started
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy resolver: no suitable found, using fallback.
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.fallback.FallbackNetworkProxy]: Fallback system proxy resolver: no http_proxy variable found
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy reloading succeeded.
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy - mode: direct
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy: fell to default (correct if direct mode went before)
INFO [org.netbeans.ui.metrics.laf]: USG_LOOK_AND_FEEL
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.cnd.utils.cache.CndFileUtils]: C/C++ File Utils: using case-sensitive file system
INFO [org.netbeans.ui.metrics.vcs]: USG_VCS_CLIENT
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.php.editor.parser.GSFPHPParser]: Parsing of big PHP files enabled: false (max size: 5,000,000)
Diagnostic information
Input arguments:
    -Djdk.home=/usr/lib/jvm/default-runtime
    -Dnetbeans.default_userdir_root=/home/mopsyd/.netbeans
    -Dnetbeans.dirs=/usr/lib/netbeans/nb:/usr/lib/netbeans/ergonomics:/usr/lib/netbeans/ide:/usr/lib/netbeans/extide:/usr/lib/netbeans/java:/usr/lib/netbeans/apisupport:/usr/lib/netbeans/webcommon:/usr/lib/netbeans/websvccommon:/usr/lib/netbeans/enterprise:/usr/lib/netbeans/mobility:/usr/lib/netbeans/profiler:/usr/lib/netbeans/python:/usr/lib/netbeans/php:/usr/lib/netbeans/identity:/usr/lib/netbeans/harness:/usr/lib/netbeans/cnd:/usr/lib/netbeans/cndext:/usr/lib/netbeans/dlight:/usr/lib/netbeans/groovy:/usr/lib/netbeans/extra:/usr/lib/netbeans/javacard:/usr/lib/netbeans/javafx:
    -Dnetbeans.home=/usr/lib/netbeans/platform
    -Dnetbeans.importclass=org.netbeans.upgrade.AutoUpgrade
    -XX:+UseStringDeduplication
    -Xss2m
    -Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true
    -Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true
    -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true
    -Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true
    -Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true
    -Dplugin.manager.check.updates=false
    -Dnetbeans.extbrowser.manual_chrome_plugin_install=yes
    --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.ref=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.text=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.event=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-modules=jdk.jshell
    --add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=java.desktop/java.awt.peer=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=java.desktop/com.sun.beans.editors=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt.im=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=java.desktop/com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=java.base/sun.reflect.annotation=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.classfile=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.javap=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.X11=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.synth=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.desktop/com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.shell=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.im=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED
    -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions
    -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
    -XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/mopsyd/.netbeans/13/var/log/heapdump.hprof
    -Djava.security.manager=allow
Compiler: HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
Heap memory usage: initial 248.0MB maximum 3525.5MB
Non heap memory usage: initial 2.4MB maximum -1b
Garbage collector: PS Scavenge (Collections=9 Total time spent=0s)
Garbage collector: PS MarkSweep (Collections=3 Total time spent=0s)
Classes: loaded=12341 total loaded=12341 unloaded 0
INFO [org.netbeans.core.ui.warmup.DiagnosticTask]: Total memory 16,629,919,744
INFO [null]: Total physical memory 16,629,919,744
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor]: Task: org.netbeans.modules.csl.navigation.ClassMemberNavigatorSourceFactory$ProxyElementScanningTask@44fa3011 : class org.netbeans.modules.csl.navigation.ClassMemberNavigatorSourceFactory$ProxyElementScanningTask ignored cancel for 1,188 ms.
INFO [org.netbeans.ui.metrics.php]: Existing PHP project opened [frameworks: ].
INFO [org.netbeans.ui.metrics.web.clientproject]: HTML5 project was opened [browser ID: Chrome.INTEGRATED, tests: NO, cordova: NO, Gruntfile.js: NO, bower.json: YES, package.json: YES, gulpfile.js: YES, selenium: NO, JS platforms: ].
INFO [org.netbeans.ui.metrics.php]: Existing PHP project opened [frameworks: ].
INFO [null]: Last record repeated 2 more times.
INFO [org.netbeans.ui.metrics.web.clientproject]: HTML5 project was opened [browser ID: Chrome.INTEGRATED, tests: NO, cordova: NO, Gruntfile.js: NO, bower.json: NO, package.json: NO, gulpfile.js: NO, selenium: NO, JS platforms: ].
INFO [org.netbeans.ui.metrics.php]: Existing PHP project opened [frameworks: ].
INFO [org.netbeans.ui.metrics.web.clientproject]: HTML5 project was opened [browser ID: Chrome.INTEGRATED, tests: NO, cordova: NO, Gruntfile.js: NO, bower.json: NO, package.json: YES, gulpfile.js: YES, selenium: NO, JS platforms: ].
INFO [org.netbeans.ui.metrics.php]: Existing PHP project opened [frameworks: ].
INFO [null]: Last record repeated again.
INFO [org.netbeans.ui.metrics.projects]: USG_PROJECT_OPEN
INFO [org.netbeans.ui.metrics.projects]: USG_PROJECT_OPEN
INFO [org.netbeans.ui.metrics.projects]: USG_PROJECT_OPEN
INFO [null]: Last record repeated 2 more times.
INFO [org.netbeans.ui.metrics.projects]: USG_PROJECT_OPEN
INFO [org.netbeans.ui.metrics.projects]: USG_PROJECT_OPEN
INFO [org.netbeans.ui.metrics.projects]: USG_PROJECT_OPEN
INFO [org.netbeans.ui.metrics.projects]: USG_PROJECT_OPEN
INFO [null]: Last record repeated again.
INFO [org.netbeans.ui.indexing]: Indexing started, time from last indexing 0 ms.
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Resolving dependencies took: 88 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 0 binary roots took: 0 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /home/mopsyd/www/oroboros-core-documentation took: 65 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 2 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: jar:file:/usr/lib/netbeans/php/docs/phpsigfiles.zip!/phpstubs/phpruntime/ took: 25 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/PHP/RuntimeLibraries/ took: 6 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /srv/http/core took: 1,962 ms (New or modified files: 1, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /srv/http/core/tests/phpunit took: 16 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /home/mopsyd/NetBeansProjects/Intile Auction/html/core took: 38 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /usr/lib/netbeans/webcommon/jsstubs/reststubs.zip took: 119 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /usr/lib/netbeans/webcommon/jsstubs/domstubs.zip took: 13 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /home/mopsyd/www/scratchpad took: 9 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /srv/http/oroboros-core/tests/development took: 641 ms (New or modified files: 2, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /home/mopsyd/www/test took: 929 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
logMessage: MessageParams [
  type = Error
  message = "[tsserver] npm notice \nnpm notice New major version of npm available! 7.11.2 -> 8.7.0\nnpm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.7.0>\nnpm notice Run `npm install -g npm@8.7.0` to update!\nnpm notice \n"
]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /srv/http/oroboros-core took: 656 ms (New or modified files: 2, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /home/mopsyd/www/dashboard-demo took: 484 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /usr/lib/netbeans/webcommon/jsstubs/corestubs.zip took: 94 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /srv/http/dynamiq-web-application took: 823 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /srv/http/intile took: 1,689 ms (New or modified files: 7, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 16 source roots took: 7,569 ms (New or modified files: 12, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 2 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.ui.indexing]: Indexing finished, indexing took 7,870 ms.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (nu.validator.source.LocationRecorder).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.git.status.cache]: refreshAllRoots: nested repository found: /srv/http/oroboros-core/tests/development contains null
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.options.keymap.LayersBridge]: Invalid shortcut: org.openide.loaders.XMLDataObject@69171ba2[MultiFileObject@4bcdbe66[Actions/Help/master-help.xml]]
```

Comment: To be clear, you never do any _explicit_ configuration of what your NetBeans screen should look like on startup. That information exists of course, because NetBeans needs it on startup, but there is no need for a user to mess with those settings. All you need to do is set your screen to your liking (e.g. Close the **Files** and **Navigator** panels), and on restart your configuration changes will be honored. If that is not happening, post the content of the NetBeans log (**View > IDE Log**). (All this assumes you have a valid stable environment, and NetBeans is closing and starting cleanly.)

Comment: That should all be nice and tidy now, I did have to partially truncate the log so it would fit within the post limit, but I only removed non-erroring module load hashes (there were a ton), eg: `org.netbeans.modules.xml.lexer [1.45 13-00d6d969bf4d9b14e7406c9ee9cc13a61dc39655]`

If these are needed, I will have to put up a pastebin link

Comment: Also the crash I had referred to earlier were being caused by a docker container running a shell script on a cron job cycle that had a buffer overflow and locked up a sizeable portion of ram. It was not netbeans related, but it did make them occasionally compete for ram when it spun off the rails, I have already corrected this issue.

Comment: I see a big problem: you are running NetBeans 13 with JDK 8. That is not a supported combination. From the **Deployment Platforms** section of [the NetBeans 13 Release Notes](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb13/nb13.html): _"**The Apache NetBeans 13 binary releases require JDK 11+**, and officially support running on JDK 11 and JDK 17."_ I'm surprised your NetBeans 13 instance even starts. Just as a sanity check, within NetBeans can you do **Help > About** and confirm that the **Java** and **Runtime** lines in the window's details also state that you are running with JDK  8?

Comment: So to have a valid NetBeans environment you need to do one of the following: [1] Stick with NetBeans 13, and upgrade your JDK to use a JDK >= 11 (preferably an LTS release, so 11 or 17). [2] Downgrade to NetBeans 12.5 or earlier, allowing you to continue to use JDK 8. Note that you can safely install and run multiple versions of NetBeans concurrently. Of course, if you run NetBeans with a JDK >= 11, you can still compile your application code for Java 8 if necessary.

Comment: Interesting catch, I do actually have jdk 11+ on my system already. I don't know why it isn't the default. I might also have to poke around my `bashrc` to see if I had it fixed to a specific version or something

Comment: Turns out that I do have jdk 1.8.0 as well as jdk 17.0.3, however the default java path defaults to 1.8. I did not find any line in bashrc telling it to do this, might have to dig a bit.

Comment: Alright, turns out there is actually an arch linux specific issue at play. The java package wrapper requires that you run `sudo archlinux-java set <version>` manually to switch the system default. Despite that the package manager does update the system correctly, it can't do the actual "use this version as default" bit automatically. More on that here: [How to change default java without resorting to witchcraft](https://archived.forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-change-default-java-without-resorting-to-witchcraft/110840)

Everything appears to work correctly now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this was occurring due to Netbeans not using the correct Java version. I corrected this by setting the default system version of java to 17.0.3.

For Manjaro/Arch users, there is a [custom command](https://archived.forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-change-default-java-without-resorting-to-witchcraft/110840) to do this. You can run `archlinux-java status` to determine your default, and `sudo archlinux-java set <version>` to set it. Various other linux distros may differ, but there is always the universal [bash_profile method](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/) if all else fails. Mac users may take [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964709/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-java-jdk-version-on-macos), and Windows users may do it [this way](https://superuser.com/questions/1057532/how-to-change-java-version-on-windows-10).

Alternately, Netbeans has it's [own configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809366/changing-java-platform-on-which-netbeans-runs) for which version it boots with if a systemwide change does not suit your needs.